# CodeIgniter : Routing URL on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri

I just learned about routing in CodeIgniter and now I am lil bit confuse.

I have an URL like this : `http://localhost/norwin/list_group/get_product_by_group/1`

Which is:

1. **list_group** is controller,
2. **get_product_by_group** is method,
3. and **'1'** is passing parameter.

I want to minimize the URL with route. So I can have an URL like :

```
http://localhost/norwin/group/'group_name'
```

And this is my code on route.php :

```
$route['group/(:any)'] = 'list_group/get_product_by_group/$1';
```

this is my controller :

```
    public function get_product_by_group($group_name)
    {
         
            if($this->uri->segment(3))
            {
                    $this->load->database();
                    $data['product_data'] = $this->group_model->list_product_by_group($group_name);
                    $this->load->view('fend/list_product', $data);

            }
            else
            {
                    redirect('list_group');
            }

    }
```

And this is my code on view which call the controller :

```
<?= base_url('group/'. $value->group_name);?>
```

my problem is : I can not get any result of the route, it always send me to `'list_group'.`

Maybe someone here have a good approach to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the route configuration is fine. what errors you are facing?

Comment: @KamranAdil : The result is always redirect me into 'list_group'

Comment: it is redirecting you because you don't have `$this->uri->segment(3)` in your URL. You only have two segments 'group' and 'group_name'. change it to `$this->uri->segment(2)`

Comment: thanks, I didnt realize it, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being redirected because `$this->uri->segment(3)` is not returning anything as your URL `http://localhost/norwin/group/'group_name'` have only 2 segments.

Codeigniter `$this->uri->segment(n);` works in the following way.

> URL: http://localhost/norwin/group/group_name/some_test

it will return

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // group
$this->uri->segment(2); // group_name
$this->uri->segment(3); // some_test
```

you have to change  `$this->uri->segment(3)` to  `$this->uri->segment(2)`